# Email Limit for Workflow Triggers

Tags: email, limits

I was planning on using Salesforce to send emails based on workflow triggers, however, I've noticed that the limit is extremely low. 1000 wiithin 24 hours. (We get more then 1000 new accounts per day already).

For example, I was planning on doing things like...

- Send a Welcome Email when a new User Record is created. I would POST the new user using a custom `@RestResource` APEX Class.
- Send a Email when something changes on a Record...
- Send Updates to Users based on X Y Z....

I would like to perhaps use a different SMTP server or maybe use SendGrid or another mailer service. It seems really limiting otherwise?

Thoughts on this?

We send out 10k~ transactional emails daily. It would make our job a lot easier if the majority of these emails could be managed through workflow triggers.. but with such a low limit, I can't see how we could work on this.

(Edit: I want to continue using workflow triggers and mail templates where possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a virtually unlimited number of email sends, you could relay the messages through your own service via call outs. Salesforce has to limit the messages sent to reduce the chance of spam filters blocking one customer's emails and consequently black listing many customers (because filters are usually by IP address).

Basically, this would simply require an endpoint hosted in a server you control to accept REST or SOAP messages, and in turn relay that to the local SMTP. You could also find a proper email hosting company that has a REST API.

I realize that the original question was about sending "through" salesforce, but from a practical standpoint, there's no alternative than to relay. It's easy to implement and gives far more flexibility.

Comment: This was the best solution really. It's unfortunate that you can't configure SF to use your own SMTP server. What justification could there be to have such indepth configuration yet not allow customers to use their own SMTP servers?

Comment: Actually, you can enable Email Relay through support, but in a completely boneheaded manner, you're still subject to the daily mass mail limit.

Comment: I guess that's how they oversell user licences.

Answer (score 0):

The limit of Salesforce workflow email alerts is actually much higher -- 1,000 **per user** per day with an overall organization limit of 2,000,000.

Information on workflow email limits can be found here:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workflow_email_limits.htm

Comment: Hi, we've only got two users in our organization. We're pretty lean... so looking for another solution that doesn't ramp up our costs x 200. :)

Comment: Ah, well, that's a little tougher and I see why you asked. You might check out Amazon SES and SendGrid as IaaS SMTP options.